# “No registered application for this type of extension.” displays on each page in Opera 11.10

Tags: bug, status-norepro

When viewing Programmers site in Opera 11.10, I get an error message box from Opera with the following text:

> No registered application for this type of extension.

I tried to track down what causes it but I haven't found any clue. I run it on Windows 7 x64, I have the following plugins:

- Shockwave Flash - 10,2,153,1
- QuickTime Plug-in 7.6.9 - 7.6.9 (1680.9)
- Adobe Acrobat - 9.4.3.231
- 2007 Microsoft Office system - 12.0.4518.1014
- Silverlight Plug-In - 4.0.60129.0
- Windows Live Photo Gallery - 15.4.3508.1109
- Media Go Detector - 1.7.0.1

**Update:** I finally found out what causes it. Pages at Programmers try to load `house-webfont.ttf`, the URL is `http://sstatic.net/programmersmeta/img/house-webfont.ttf`. Server response has

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

It looks like Opera does not know how to handle it.

On another computer with Windows 7 and Opera 11.10 where this message does not appear, I see it requests `house-webfont.woff` which has `Content-Type` set to `application/x-woff`.

Disabling all the plugins did not make a difference.

**Update 2:** I have resolved this problem. It was connected with left-over setting of previous installs where I had ReGet installed and ReGet configured Opera to intercept downloads. The behavior of Opera changed over time… which now caused this error to be displayed.

I changed Download setting in Opera so that it displays Download dialog for `application/octet-stream` type. And custom fonts returned to Programmers pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce this -- the site loads fine for me in Opera 11.01 with no errors.

But I have no special extensions installed, it is a default Opera install.

Comment: I updated the description with my findings. It is caused by `house-webfont.ttf`; where it works, it loads `house-webfont.woff`.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this problem. It was connected with left-over setting of previous installs where I had ReGet installed and ReGet configured Opera to intercept downloads. The behavior of Opera changed over time… which now caused this error to be displayed.

I changed Download setting in Opera so that it displays Download dialog for `application/octet-stream` type. And custom fonts returned to Programmers pages.